# Can a snapshot of a given workspace in gnome be made while the screen is locked?

Tags: linux, redhat, gnome, csh

I've written a csh script, which runs on a RedHat Linux box under gnome, that periodically takes a screen snapshot as follows:

```
xwd -root -out <filename>
```

It works fine as long as the screen doesn't lock.  Unfortunately, I'm in an classified area so I have to lock my screen whenever I leave my office. I often run graphic tasks overnight and the screen will be locked the whole time.
Is there a way to take a screen snapshot on a particular workspace when the screen is locked and that workspace is not visible?

Comment: Have you considered using one of those transparent lock screens that allow you to see the screen but not to interact with it?

Comment: No.  The screen is considered classified and I can't leave my office with the screen visible.

Comment: Maybe you can use `xwd -id` or `-name` to take a screen dump of a specific window then, instead of `-root` which would also include the lock screen itself?

Comment: When I used -root the snapshots after the screen lock were all just black backgrounds; they didn't include the lock screen.

Comment: I guess the question is "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?" I.e., Does a workspace have to be visible to take a snapshot?  Or, does the frame buffer get written to memory and is that frame buffer accessible to xwd (or some other tool)?

Comment: If `xwd` doesn't get them to render, you could probably use Xnest/Xephyr or vncserver and take a screenshot inside that instead. It's not nearly as convenient though.

Comment: I've read up a little about Xnest. Were you thinking that I could run the nested server in a place where I didn't have to lock the screen?  If that were the case, I would just run X as usual from that server and run my snapshot script there as well.   Unfortunately we don't have that setup.  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Nothing in any of these comments are meant to suggest you run anything anywhere in such a way that someone can walk up to it and interact with it. You would run `xwd` and your software in Xnest on your locked desktop. Since your actual desktop is locked, no one can access the nested desktop. Since the nested desktop wouldn't know it's implicitly locked, chances are it'll take screenshots properly. A vncserver would definitely work, since it does not require displaying anything anywhere to run X software and take screenshots if it.